# Magento - How to query admin's role name?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am trying to get the name of the role of the currently logged in admin. I can get the admin user, but I can't figure out how to query their role name. The Magento docs are weak =/

```
$usr = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
```

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spoke too soon... I got the role name as follows:

```
$roleId = implode('', Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRoles());
$roleName = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->load($roleId)->getRoleName();
```

Comment: You can also get the role by

Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole();

This will return a role object that you can pull all the data from.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code you will get the role of current user

> ```
> $admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
> $adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserId();
> $role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();
> $role_name = $role_data['role_name'];
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleName();

M.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one that may be a little friendlier:

```
$acl = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl();
$acl->isAllowed($user->getAclRole(), 'admin/foo/bar'));
```

That will return a boolean. `$user` is an `admin/user` object.