# Magento - how to check non-current admin user against role resources?

Tags: magento

I know how to use isAllowed to check if the current user has access to this or that role resource. However, isAllowed() does not seem to work for any other than the currently logged in user.

I need to produce a list of administrator users with a specific permission at role resource level, how would I go about that ?

Answer (score 1):

[Magento - How to query admin's role name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024564/magento-how-to-query-admins-role-name)